# Apache : How to Use Rewrite Engine Inside Alias

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, mod-alias

I have this alias configuration:

```
Alias /test/ "D:/WWW/Test/"
<Directory "D:/WWW/Test/">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Then inside `D:/WWW/Test/` directory, I put .htaccess with the following configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteRule ^([^.]*\.css)$ resources/$1 [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

I just want to redirect all request from `localhost/test/css/*` to `localhost/test/resources/css/*`.

But it seems that the `.htaccess` is ignored. Even if I put `DirectoryIndex blablabla.php` , browser still displays index.html.

How to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need three things:

1. Inside `<Directory>`, allow .htaccess files with `AllowOverride All`.
2. Give the required permissions of mod_rewrite with `Options FollowSymLinks`.
3. Inside the .htaccess, include `RewriteBase /test/`.