# Created a symlink doesn't work with download managers? Also .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, http-headers, download, symlink

I am trying to setup a small web file server. I have download some software and I am trying to learn how to configure it to download files when I click the link rather than attempt to open them in my browser

My files are stored in a different directory than my web directory. So I made a symlink and an alias and it seems to work! But I am not sure what I have to do from here
So I found *.htaccess* info saying it can force files to download. So I did this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|zip|avi|mkv|mp4)$" >
    ForceType application/octet-stream
    Header add Content-Disposition "attachment"
</FilesMatch>
```

The issue is it does not work. Would this work in the symlink directory? I have tried placing it my index and in the symlink folder. It doesn't work.

One other thing is I can right click a link on my website and click "save link as" and this lets me download the file. However if I click "copy link address" and paste it into my download manager it does not work. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: possible dublicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/10067276/1001563

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251305/apache-how-to-use-rewrite-engine-inside-alias