# apache htaccess rewrite with alias

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We are changing our domain name and this is meant to work for stand alone applications. In Apache virtual host file the DocumentRoot is /var/www/website/html, not /var/www/example/html as in this block:

```
Alias /apps/dept /var/www/example/html/apps/dept
<Directory "/var/www/example/html/apps/dept/">
   Options FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order allow,deny
   Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I put an .htaccess file in /var/www/example/html/apps/dept directory as follows:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /apps/dept/
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.orgname.state.tx.us/apps/dept [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.orgname.texas.gov/apps/dept/$1 [L,R=301]
```

This seems to follow what is recommended here, http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html and [Apache : How to Use Rewrite Engine Inside Alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251305/apache-how-to-use-rewrite-engine-inside-alias). I see no results. The new domain has a virutal host config in the VH file, also. This same basic rewrite works for our Drupal website which does not use an alias. What changes might be necessary to have the domain name rewritten with an appended application pathname? Is the RewriteBase incorrect?

Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you only want to redirect `/apps/dept/`, correct? This should work. Place it as an `.htaccess` or in the Apache config for `example.orgname.state.tx.us` and all should work as expected.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/apps/dept/(.*)$ http://example.orgname.texas.gov/apps/dept/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

So now, any requests going to this URL

```
http://example.orgname.state.tx.us/apps/dept/
```

Will now go to this URL:

```
http://example.orgname.texas.gov/apps/dept/
```

And any request parameters to the right of the URL will be passed along as well.

**EDIT** Just reread what you wrote here:

> I put an .htaccess file in /var/www/example/html/apps/dept directory
>   as follows.

The `.htaccess` I described above should be placed in `/var/www/example/html/` and not in the `/apps/dept` subdirectory.

But if you want the same behavior from an `.htaccess` placed in `/apps/dept` then use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.orgname.texas.gov/apps/dept/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

This way any request made from `/apps/dept` will to to `example.orgname.texas.gov/apps/dept/` including subdirectories of `/apps/dept` such as `/apps/dept/test_app1`, `/apps/dept/test_app2` or `/apps/dept/test_app3`.

Or perhaps try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://example.orgname.texas.gov/apps/dept/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

Note I removed the `^` which would force the `RewriteRule` to match the beginning of the URL.

Comment: I'd like to redirect applications that are in directories below the /apps/dept/ directory.

Comment: Hope to include these directories: http://example.on.state.tx.us/apps/dept/myapp/ to http://example.on.texas.gov/apps/dept/myapp. There are about 10 applications in the dept dir.

Comment: Thanks. I tried a copy/paste of the above .htaccess contents in the /apps/dept/ dir and this returned https://example.on.texas.gov/var/www/example/html/apps/dept/example.on.texas.gov/apps/dept/   in the URL box of the browser. Looks like the reverse alias is in it. So close.

Comment: It works for the /apps/dept/ directory but not for the apps in the subdirectories.

Comment: You are correct. This solution works and this issue is resolved. Thanks.

Comment: Solution runs all apache requests for host files within path through the redirect rule. Is there a performance hit in this, rather than sending only orgnm\.tx\.us requests through the rule? There is VH config for the new domain, orgnm.texas.gov, so no need to catch those. Just a hunch.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot match Request URI in `%{HTTP_HOST}` variable, it matches only domain name. Chang your rule to:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /apps/dept/

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.orgname\.state\.tx\.us$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.orgname.texas.gov/apps/dept/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This works for the /apps/dept/ directory only, but not for directories under dept. Is there a way to take care of all the app dirs under the dept without doing and .htaccess for each application?